# How to disable back button in external library's activity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using this library:
https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker

How do I disable the physical back button for this place picker activity?

[image]

This is the code to open this activity:

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.sucho.placepicker.AddressData;
import com.sucho.placepicker.Constants;
import com.sucho.placepicker.PlacePicker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        Intent intent = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()
                .setLatLong(40.748672, -73.985628)  // Initial Latitude and Longitude the Map will load into
                .showLatLong(true)  // Show Coordinates in the Activity
                .setMapZoom(12.0f)  // Map Zoom Level. Default: 14.0
                .onlyCoordinates(true) //Get only Coordinates from Place Picker
                .build(this);

        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                AddressData addressData = data.getParcelableExtra(Constants.ADDRESS_INTENT);
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

I know the following is how to disable the physical back button generally, but how do I do it in this case?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing because you don't want them to leave when it's pressed
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to change the source code of the respective activity in that lib?

Comment: Then ask developers of that lib to add a feature letting developers to choose whether they want a 'back' arrow in the app-bar or no.

Comment: I won't try it for you, but the basic path is to checkout their source-code and to compile it yourself, either as a .jar file which you can then link to your project as a library, or to make it as the part of your project, but in this last case it'll be compiled with every your build.

Comment: Panjeet edits to question are welcome but note that edit should add clarification or more details to questions but you have changed the complete question itself which cause severe issues with post. Please don't change the track of question

Comment: Rolled back the edit. A bounty is not an ask-as-many-questions-as-you-can-in-7-days pass.

Comment: @Panjeet - please ask a new question instead of editing this one. Trying to ask multiple questions under a single bounty is disrespectful to those who have taken the time to answer your original question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Define a as Local

```
 private static boolean a = false;
```

and Override onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(a)
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't funny. Are you trolling? Why would you edit a question to a completely different question with existing answers already posted?

Comment: No. Anyone who checks edits will know the truth. Opening the about device page and disabling the back button in an external activity are nowhere near the same question.

Comment: @Panjeet Write a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217422/discussion-between-ray-wu-and-panjeet).

Answer (score 6):

How about extending the library? The classes are not final and I think all you need is to extend the Activity class and may be builder class. First check the [activityClass](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/83b191404b2d53da30f14fd7c671fe0b3eb9c4b6/plugin-places/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/places/picker/ui/PlacePickerActivity.java). And this may be the possible extended class.

```
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.places.R;

class YourPickerActivity extends PlacePickerActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addBackButtonListener()
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing because you don't want them to leave when it's pressed
}

private void addBackButtonListener() {
    ImageView backButton = findViewById(R.id.mapbox_place_picker_toolbar_back_button);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //doNothing
        }
    });
    //or hide the button
    }
}
```

And as the documentation said, you should use a builder class the start the activity. [BuilderClass](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/83b191404b2d53da30f14fd7c671fe0b3eb9c4b6/plugin-places/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/places/picker/PlacePicker.java) I think the builder class is final and so you cannot extends that class, but the class itself do only two jobs: adding the access token and adding the placePicker options. So if you call yourCustomPickerActivity with the intent data with the key names from this [class](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/77f08d39117a967a536a5b25a5189907d38ba4d7/plugin-places/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/places/common/PlaceConstants.java)

Comment: The [builder](https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker/blob/ddd47705478df34905aa8086816eef99caa2576c/placepicker/src/main/java/com/sucho/placepicker/PlacePicker.kt) and [PickerActivity](https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker/blob/ddd47705478df34905aa8086816eef99caa2576c/placepicker/src/main/java/com/sucho/placepicker/PlacePickerActivity.kt) are not extendable. You may copy/paste the codes from PickerActivity, modify onBackPress and starts the activity in same way as in builder. i think second lib use google map api and nothing special and it might be better to implement it yourself.

Comment: If so, make a pull request or open a issues at the library repo. I would prefer implementation the google map lib by yourself as it would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 5):

A solution could be to create an abstract Activity which override `onBackPressed()`. Then all your activities need to extend this new Activity.

```
public abstract class NoBackPressedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing because you don't want them to leave when it's pressed
    }
}
```

A problem of this solution is, if you need to extend another type of activity.

Don't forget, it's not recommended to disable `onBackPressed()` in the all app.

Comment: Are you extending this `PlaceSelectionPluginActivity` sample class ?

Comment: You just copy pasted the code from mapBox plugin example. Thats's why i'm not understanding which activity you're trying to extend.

Comment: Ok, so why you cannot use the proposed answer as your activity only extend `AppCompatActivity`.

Like `public class PlaceSelectionPluginActivity extends NoBackPressedActivity`

Comment: And did you tried to override the `onBackPressed()` in your `PlaceSelectionPluginActivity ` activity ? 

I guess you tried and it doesn't work. That's why you're looking for a global solution which disable it everywhere in the app.